# Is the base access defined correctly in the C# Language Specification 4.0?

Tags: c#, grammar, language-lawyer

While I was looking through the `C# Language Specification v4.0` I noticed that there is a group of rules defined as this:

```
invocationExpression:
    primaryExpression '(' argumentList? ')'

primary-expression: 
    primary-no-array-creation-expression
    array-creation-expression

primary-no-array-creation-expression:
    literal
    simple-name
    parenthesized-expression
    member-access
    invocation-expression
    element-access
    this-access
    base-access
    post-increment-expression
    post-decrement-expression
    object-creation-expression
    delegate-creation-expression
    anonymous-object-creation-expression
    typeof-expression
    checked-expression
    unchecked-expression 
    default-value-expression
    anonymous-method-expression

base-access:
    'base'   '.'   identifier
    'base'   '['   argument-list   ']'
```

When I tried to match this statement (which is correct statement by the way, I've seen it used in a project)

```
base.VisitList<T>(list, visitor);
```

to the given rules I didn't see a way how this can be done. Shouldn't be `base-access` defined as:

```
 base-access:
        'base'   '.'   identifier type-parameter-list(opt)
        'base'   '['   argument-list   ']'
```

or something similar to this in such a way the grammar be able to capture the statement?

**EDIT** The example I saw was in the C# version of the project `db4o` and it is something like this (I deleted most of the declarations and left only the important ones)

```
internal abstract class ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected virtual void VisitList<T>()
    {
    }
}

internal class HashCodeCalculation : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override void VisitList<T>()
    {
        base.VisitList<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It *does* seem like an error in the 4.0 spec.

Comment: The language for `base access` in the 5.0 spec seems to be identical to the language in the 1.2 spec (earliest I can find, predates generics). I'd say they've just not been keeping that part of the spec up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It indeed looks like there might be an error in the specification.

The way to parse the expression

```
this.VisitList<T>(list, visitor)
```

is as follows:

```
invocation-expression

primary-expression '(' argumentList? ')'

primary-no-array-creation-expression '(' argumentList? ')'

member-access '(' argumentList? ')'

primary-expression '.' identifier type-argument-listopt '(' argumentList? ')'

this-access '.' identifier type-argument-listopt '(' argumentList? ')'

'this' '.' identifier type-argument-listopt '(' argumentList? ')'
```

And so on.

In other words, `this-access` is defined as

```
this-access:
    'this'
```

It would make a lot of sense if `base-access` were defined as

```
base-access:
    'base'
```

Then the way to parse the expression

```
base.VisitList<T>(list, visitor)
```

would be as follows:

```
invocation-expression

primary-expression '(' argumentList? ')'

primary-no-array-creation-expression '(' argumentList? ')'

member-access '(' argumentList? ')'

primary-expression '.' identifier type-argument-listopt '(' argumentList? ')'

base-access '.' identifier type-argument-listopt '(' argumentList? ')'

'base' '.' identifier type-argument-listopt '(' argumentList? ')'
```

And so on.

But it isn't.

Comment: I agree, seems the spec is not correct. Or the compiler is not keeping to the spec ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is really valid C# code. Maybe you saw it in C++?

The following code fails to compile with a syntax error:

```
public class VisitList<T> : List<T>
{
    public VisitList(int n)
        : base.VisitList<T>(n)
    {

    }
}
```

This works:

```
public class VisitList<T> : List<T>
{
    public VisitList(int n)
        : base(n)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The example I gave is from the C# version of `db4o`. You can check out my update.

Comment: Ok, that looks more reasonable. How is `identifier` declared?

Comment: It is defined as sequence of characters which obeys certain rules like: an identifier starts only with either a letter or underscore `_` - the usual stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In [Standard ECMA-334 **5th Edition** / December 2017 C# Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

Section 12.7.9 Base access, page 151

it now reads:

```
base-access:
base . identifier type-argument-listopt
base [ argument-list ]
```

Since this was changed that seems to be an acknowledgement that the 4th edition did indeed have a flaw or omission.